# Angular2 form gets submitted instead of running the onSubmit() method

Tags: angular

I have the following component:

**Template**

```html
<div class="hide" id="login-contents">
    <form *ngIf="!current_user" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text"
                   #username
                   id="username"
                   class="form-control"
                   required
                   placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password"
                   #password
                   id="password"
                   class="form-control"
                   required
                   placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit"
                class="btn btn-block btn-primary"
                [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Component Typescript**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'login-form',
    templateUrl: '/app/form.login.html'
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
    submitted = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Form initialised");
    }

    onSubmit(event: any, username: string, password: string) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('onSubmit');
        this.submitted = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

According to the `onInit` stuff (added for debugging reasons), the form component gets loaded (of course, as I see the form itself). The `preventDefault()` calls and `return false` are my tries to prevent an actual submit (and thus, a full page reload) that happens when I press the Login button. Also, the Login button is not disabled, even when the form is not filled (and thus, is not valid).

I already tried to use `<button type="button">` instead of `type="submit"`, but the `onSubmit()` method doesn’t get called. The same happens (or more like not happens) if I move the `(ngsubmit)="onSubmit()"` to the button as `(click)="onSubmit()"`. I start to suspect the problem is somewhere deeper, not even in this component.

What may I miss? I’m using `2.0.0-rc.6`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()"
```

instead of

```
 <button type="submit"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the question; I already tried it without success. The `onSubmit()` method doesn’t get called.

Comment: I updated my answer. It's a combination of my old answer and BeetleJuice's answer. Did you try it this way?

Comment: Yes I did. `onSubmit()` is still not called.

Comment: How do you load the `FormsModule`? If `<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()"` doesn't call `onSubmit()`, there is something more substantial wrong with your app. That's not related to forms at all.

Comment: That’s possible (as I mentioned it in the last edit). In `app.module` I added `FormsModule` to `imports: []`. In the SystemJS config, `map.app` contains a `'@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js'` line.

Comment: No I can’t. In fact, my component works just fine [there](https://embed.plnkr.co/x36vek/).

Comment: Then it's not caused by the code in your question and quite hard for us to provide support. You could try to purge `node_modules` and start over.

Answer (score 1):

If @Gunter's suggestion doesn't work, you can always just take control of what happens.  Remove `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"`, and in the `<button>`, do

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()"...
```

Comment: Still the same; with `type="submit"` it gets submitted and reloaded, with `type="button"` nothing happens (not even in the console).

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai look in the console for any error, and in network requests for any `404 not found` or other problems.  Maybe the `FormsModule` was not properly imported into this component's module

Comment: There’s none. I was indeed missing the Forms module due to a problem in my SystemJS configuration, but I have solved that already. It also worth mention I have since restarted `lite` :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem, that submitting the form was doing a REST call to a dev server called `json-server` (https://github.com/typicode/json-server) - and the app was running using angular-cli's `ng serve` command.
And despite writing `event.preventDefault()`, the page was doing a reload!
(No matter if coming from `<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">` or `<button (click)="onSubmit()">`!)

The problem was, that the json-server is extremely smart and modifies the json file you let it serve! And this triggers the ng-serve-watcher - because my served json file resided inside my application codes `/assets` folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the (submit) command like so

```
<form #frm="ngForm" (submit)="submit(value)">
...
</form>
```